# Does a bijection between sets mean that they must both be bounded/unbounded?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The specific example is the set of A which is a subset of the set of real numbers and is bounded, and the set of −A:={−a:a∈A}. There is a bijection given by f: A to -A and with f(x)=-x

Therefore as every element of -A corresponds to exactly one element of A it must also be bounded

Edit: Thanks for the counterexamples

Comment: So I must assume you don't believe in $\arctan$.

Comment: No: consider $f : (0, 1] \to [1, \infty)$ defined by $f(x) = x^{-1}$. $f$ is a bijection (in fact, a homeomorphism), but $(0, 1]$ is bounded while $[1, \infty)$ is not.

Comment: Boundedness of the image of $f$ here depends on the details of $f$.  Consider $A = \{1, 2, 3, \dots\}$, the positive integers and $f:A \rightarrow \Bbb{R}: a \mapsto 1/a$.  This takes the unbounded $A$ to a bounded set.  Doing this in reverse takes a bounded set to an unbounded set.
For your particular $f$, can you show $|f(x)| = |x|$, so that any bound on $x$ is also a bound on $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

No, consider the function $f \colon (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \, x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$. $(0,1)$ ist bounded, however $\operatorname{im}(f)=(1,\infty)$ isnt.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your function, then sure.

But here's a counter-example to the more general setting. Take $A=\mathbb N_{\geq 1}$ and $B=\left\{\frac1n\mid n\in A\right\}$. Then there is an obvious bijectiom between $A$ and $B$, but $A$ is not bounded, while $B$ is.